# Php/MySQL Adding time from a form to current date then inserting into DB

Tags: php, mysql, date, addition, strtotime

I've been looking everywhere for information on how to add an amount of time (months) specified in a form on a Php website to current date, and then adding this date into MySQL database Date (for ex. 2014-03-03) field (if using Date is even possible here).

Could You tell me what should I use to take the current date without time, add a custom amount of months to it (using strtotime I assume, but it uses syntax like +1 days, where I have a variable from a form), and then input it into database field type "Date"? I could change the DB field type to Datetime or Timestamp if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mktime for this:

```
<?php

print date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + 6, date("d"), date("Y")));
```

Here, I have added 6 months to the date.

Comment: I have tried using this like so: "$ExpDate=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + 6, date("d"), date("Y"))); but it still gives me 0000s in the database. Can this be used with "Date" field type of mysql DB? The insert command that I used: $sql = "INSERT INTO orders  (user,plan_id,adress,email,phone,expires) VALUES ('$user','$id','$adress','$mail', '$phone','$ExpDate')";

Comment: What do you mean?  The code above prints `2014-09-03`.

Comment: You mean that you are using a different field type in your table than you are wanting to use?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what was wrong, adding the date works now! The only thing left to sort out is.. how do I add a number from a submit form as the amount of months to add with the mktime? Instead of constantly adding +6? Something like "$ExpDate=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + $_POST["expires"], date("d"), date("Y"))); "?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Of course you need to make sure and validate `$_POST['xxxxxx']` before ever using it.  But yeah, generally that will do what you want.

Comment: Thank You very much for helping me out, I've only been playing around with php for a few days, feels great to actually get something to work. Could you tell me how do I mark your answer as the "correct one"? I'm new to the site as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

following this logic it should be pretty easy to save your date in mysql. =)
   strtotime is a great function because its always very  easy to understand what's going on at a glance.

```
$days = $_POST['days'];  // data from your form

$currentTime = strtotime('today');  // you can also use time() or put in your own date
$nextDay = strtotime('+'.$days.' days', $currentTime);  // add number of days from form
$nextDay = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $currentTime);  // format the time from unix timestamp into mysql format
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that I need to add the amount of days/months FROM A FORM to the current date, not a preset amount like 1 day.

Comment: okay.. so just get the number of days or whatever from your form and plug that in.  look at my updated answer..